# How to define custom cache lifetime for custom content elements?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Shouldn't TypoScript `cache` work for custom content elements like this:

```
tt_content {
    my_custom_element =< lib.contentElement
    my_custom_element {
        // tested also with stdWrap.cache
        cache {
            key = my_custom_element
            // 10 seconds to test
            lifetime = 10
        }
        templateName = MyCustomElement
        dataProcessing.10 = Example\Project\DataProcessing\FetchDataProcessor
        dataProcessing.10 {
            fetchUri = https://www.example.com/resource
            as = fetched_data
        }
    }
}
```

...or do I interpret it the wrong way?
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Cache.html
I would expect to define a custom cache lifetime for this content element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
tt_content {
    // COA_INT to ensure the block .my_custom_element isn't cached
    my_custom_element = COA_INT
    my_custom_element {
        10 =< lib.contentElement
        10 {
            // Re-add cache for the block .10
            cache {
                // Use UID of content element when user can edit content of it
                key = my_custom_element_{field:uid}
                key.insertData = 1
                // For test currently 10 seconds
                lifetime = 10
            }
            templateName = MyCustomElement
            dataProcessing.10 = Example\Project\DataProcessing\FetchDataProcessor
            dataProcessing.10 {
                fetchUri = https://www.example.com/resource
                as = fetched_data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BUT it has (huge) drawbacks:**

- The page HTML, where the content element is placed on, won't be cached by the browser.
- And a static file cache extension won't work for this pages too.

Answer (score 0):

Hi yes this stores you element for 5 secomds into the caching Framework after that it will be rerendered.

The key should be unique for each variant of your Content. As you have a custom Content element here your editors are probably allowed to enter data. Best ro include the uid of the Content element in the key.

Also 5 seconds is really short. Maybe you want to implement a plugin and not a content element

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This code is an example code. In real life the custom CE fetches data from an external source within a DataProcessor. Since the CE can be available in several pages, they should be invalidated to the same time (like 5 am).

I extended the example.